# d3 click event handle(object)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need click event handle in **D3.js** i.e the event object on click.
My code

```
 node.enter().append("svg:circle")
      .on('click', function(data,index){

       });
```

But I want **event object** like this in jquery

```
$('element').on('click',function(event){
    //Like the 'event' object here
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
node.enter().append("svg:circle")
    .on('click', function(data,index){
         d3.event; // => Original DOM Event
     });
```

» **[More info about d3.event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_event).**